# Pycharm shows no coverage statistics, but shows coverage in code files

Tags: pycharm, pytest, code-coverage

I'm trying to see the code coverage of our test in the coverage panel from pycharm. Everything works as it should, with code coverage appearing in the files, but I can't seem to get any statistics in the coverage panel. It stays empty. I've tried removing the .coverage files, restarting pycharm, adding `--cov` and `--no-cov` to the parameters of the test configuration. What can be the reason the statistics don't show up?

[image: Code with coverage on the left, empty statistics on the right]

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are running coverage counting using PyCharm button looking like "shield with green play button" [image: The button icon] then you use not `pytest-cov` but `coverage.py`. `coverage.py` can be partly configured by PyCharm settings (Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Coverage). Most settings must be set in the `.coveragerc` file.
2. I set `coverage.py` up to ignore my `tests` directory.

```
...
omit =
    */tests*
...
```

`Coverage View` (the pane on the right on the image in the question) does not show the statistics for `tests` but anyway the line hit for the files in 'tests' are shown in editor.
So `Program` can become "omit" for example.

**Another idea**: the name of the directory with the code contains some not visible characters that causes a bug preventing the statistics from showing.